# How to save only a specific item using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using EF4 in my web application.

Currently, when I want to save a specific item, I change its properties, and then call `SaveChanges()`.

But then all changes in the application are committed.

How can I commit changes of only specific item?

Comment: Do you create one context for your entire application? It's better to only create a context when and where you need it.

Comment: How you manage the lifetime of Context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new context and attach your specific item to this new context. Then call `SaveChanges()` of the new context.